# I thought tonight was <about> us hanging out

Tags: meaning

> 1. I think marriage is **about** two equal partners sharing a life together.
> 2. I thought tonight was **about** us hanging out, what's with inviting this girl?

Here, I'm wondering the function of "about". what's the meaning of "about" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preposition about has several meanings. One meaning is about + topic/subject. Collins Dictionary has it in no. 1: relating to, concerning, on the subject of. A bit more formal is on + topic.

http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/about

Curiously Oald does not have about + topic.  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/about_1